# Remove duplicates and sort a list

Tags: list, scheme

I am trying to write a procedure that takes a list that may or may not include duplicates, and then return that list without duplicates, and in sorted order. What I came up with so far is:

```
(define (remove-duplicated list)
    (if (null? list)
       '()
        (if (= (car list) (cadr list))
            (cdr list)
            (cons (car list) (remove-duplicates (cdr list))))))
```

I'm not quite sure what the problem is, besides sorting the list. For example, if I input

```
(remove-duplicates '(3 3 4 5 6 6 7))
```

returns

```
(3 4 5 6 6 7)
```

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the input list might be *sorted* slipped my mind. What I'm about to describe will work for removing duplicate elements from any list, sorted or not. For the general case of removing duplicates in a list, you have to search the current element in the rest of the list, using [`member`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._member%29%29) for that.

Also, you have to advance the recursion in both cases, and be aware that in the last line you're calling [`remove-duplicates`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._remove-duplicates%29%29) (which is a built-in procedure in some interpreters, so maybe you don't have to implement it from scratch!), but you named the procedure `remove-duplicated`. As a side note, it's a bad idea to name a parameter [`list`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._list%29%29), that'll clash with a built-in function - I took the liberty of renaming it. This will fix the problems, and it's a more general solution:

```
; if the input list is not sorted, use this
(define (remove-duplicated lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      '()
      (if (member (car lst) (cdr lst))  ; changes here
          (remove-duplicated (cdr lst)) ; and here
          (cons (car lst)
                (remove-duplicated (cdr lst))))))
```

Now, if the input list is *sorted* to begin with, this is how to fix your code. Most of my comments apply, except that you don't have to use `member` and the base case is a little different:

```
; if the input list is sorted, use this
(define (remove-duplicated lst)
  (if (or (null? lst) (null? (cdr lst))) ; changes here
      lst
      (if (= (car lst) (cadr lst))
          (remove-duplicated (cdr lst))  ; and here
          (cons (car lst)
                (remove-duplicated (cdr lst))))))
```

Either way, the procedure will work as expected as long as you use the right one for the input (the first implementation is for sorted *or* unsorted input lists, the second one works only for sorted lists):

```
(remove-duplicated '(3 3 4 5 6 6 7)) ; sorted input, both implementations work
=> '(3 4 5 6 7)
```

Finally, if you need to make sure that the output list will always be sorted, but have no guarantees that the input list was sorted, then use my first implementation of `remove-duplicated` and sort it afterwards, check your interpreter to find out which sorting procedures are available - the following will work in Racket:

```
(sort (remove-duplicated '(3 6 3 7 4 5 6)) <) ; using my first remove-duplicated
=> '(3 4 5 6 7)
```

… Or sort the list first and then use my second implementation of `remove-duplicated`. You have so many options to solve this problem!

```
(remove-duplicated (sort '(3 6 3 7 4 5 6) <)) ; using my second remove-duplicated
=> '(3 4 5 6 7)
```

Comment: The OP wants a sorted list without duplicates.  If `list` is already sorted, then it's OK to simply discard an element when the next element is the same;  those are the only places that duplicates could be in a _sorted_ list.  OP still needs to `remove-duplicated` from `(cdr list)`, though, as I've explained in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20085977/1281433).

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor the fact that the list was sorted slipped my mind. I fixed my answer, thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Well, I'm not sure that the question makes it clear that the list _is_ sorted, but the comparison of the first and second elements makes a lot more sense if OP is assuming that it is sorted.

Answer (score 0):

> a fairly simple procedure that will take in a list that may or may not
>   include duplicats, and then return that list without any duplicates
>   included, and in sorted order.

There are at least two ways that you could do this:

- sort the list once the duplicates are removed; or
- remove the duplicates after the list has been sorted.

[Óscar López pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20084810/1281433) that

> [Your] implementation fails because you're only testing for two
>   consecutive values, you have to search the current element in the rest
>   of the list, use member for that.

This will be an issue if you remove the duplicates *before* sorting, since a given element in the list could have duplicates anywhere else in the list.  However, if you sort the list first, then you would be guaranteed that any duplicate elements *do* immediately follow the original, so you wouldn't need to check the whole list.  Removing duplicates is easier if the list is sorted, but sorting a list isn't really any easier after duplicate elements are removed, so it really does make sense to sort the list first and *then* remove duplicates.    (I suppose you could be even more efficient, and write your own `sort-and-remove-duplicates` procedure, but almost certainly not really necessary.)

Your code, if you're assuming that `list` is already sorted, is *almost* correct.  There are two adjustments necessary:

1. In the base case, you're only checking whether `(null? list)`.  However, for a non-null list, you then compare `(car list)` and `(cadr list)`, but if `list` only has one element, then `(cadr list)` is an error.  Fortunately, lists with only one element have no duplicates, so your base case can be `(or (null? list) (null? (cdr list)))`.
2. The *then* part of the second `if` needs to be `(remove-duplicated (cdr list))`, not `(cdr list)`,  since `list` can still have more duplicates farther down (e.g., `(x x x ...)` or `(x x y y ...)`).

This is your code with those modifications and some comments:

```
(define (remove-duplicated list)
  ;; remove duplicates from a *sorted* list.  Because the 
  ;; list is sorted, any duplicates of an element will
  ;; immediately follow the first occurrence of the element.
  ;;---------------------------------------------------------
  ;; If the list has the form () or (x)
  (if (or (null? list)
          (null? (cdr list)))
      ;; then it has no duplicates, so return it
      list
      ;; otherwise, if the list looks like (x x ...)
      (if (= (car list) (cadr list))
          ;; then you can discard the first element, but you
          ;; still need to remove duplicates from the rest of
          ;; the list, since there can be more duplicates later
          (remove-duplicated (cdr list))
          ;; otherwise, you need the first element of the list
          ;; and can simply remove-duplicated from the rest.
          (cons (car list) (remove-duplicated (cdr list))))))
```

This works as expected:

```
(remove-duplicated '(1 1 2 3 3 4 5 6))
;=> '(1 2 3 4 5 6)
```